# android -how to listen to SpeakerPhone change

Tags: android, speakerphone

I'd like to be able to listen to on/off events of the android native speakerphone button.

Realizing i could spawn a child thread and keep checking for AudioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();  thats just going to kill battery life etc etc.  Is there a listener for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from **API 29**, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` using the Intent filter `AudioManager.ACTION_SPEAKERPHONE_STATE_CHANGED`.

Documentation is available in the Android official page [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#ACTION_SPEAKERPHONE_STATE_CHANGED).

Unfortunately I didn't found any other way except polling, for APIs < 29.